# ClassNotFoundException at Runtime

Tags: java, ant

I am new in Java and I have a problem with java application.

I build an app with Ant and when I try to run application with `java -jar appName.jar` there was an error `ClassNotFoundException`.

The problem is that in main class I have imported libs like this:

```
import de.SigX.Configuration.IniFile;
import de.signotec.STPad.api.SigPadApi;
import de.signotec.STPad.api.SigPadDevice;
import de.signotec.STPad.api.SigPadFacade;
import de.signotec.STPad.api.exceptions.SigPadApiException;
```

The exception throws only on

```
de.signotec.STPad.api.exceptions.SigPadApiException
```

Anyone know why?

EDIT:

Build.xml structure:

```
-<project basedir="." default="default" name="Test">
<description>Builds, tests, and runs the project Test.</description>
<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
-<target name="-post-jar">
<copy file="lib\libSTPadJava.so" todir="${dist.dir}\lib"/>

<copy file="lib\libSTPadJava64.so" todir="${dist.dir}\lib"/>
<copy file="lib\STPadJava64.dll" todir="${dist.dir}\lib"/>
<copy file="lib\STPadJava.dll" todir="${dist.dir}\lib"/>
<copy file="log4j2.json" todir="${dist.dir}"/>

<copy file="lib\property.ini" todir="${dist.dir}\lib"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: When the question is vague, the answers will also be vague. Can you show us how - in more detail - you use Ant? Also, consider using maven instead.

Comment: looks like a missing dependency in the classpath

Comment: I am using `ant -buildfile 'path to build.xml' 'name' `

Answer (score 1):

"import" keyword doesn't import or add libs to runtime. it is just a class import which helps to refer a class without providing the fully qualified name. it will only be used at compile time. 
when you run a java application through a jar file, all dependencies (jars) should be pointed through -classpath or -cp , or you should embed all those classes to the main jar file.